# How to use .debug api in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to use the `.debug` api in Scala Spark.

For instance, with:

```
val df = spark.read.format("json").load(path).as[Employee]
df.show()
df.debug()
```

I get this exceptions:

```
    java.io.NotSerializableException: ...
18/03/12 10:53:06 WARN SerializationDebugger: Exception in serialization debugger
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use explain or toDebugString**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@explain(extended:Boolean):Unit

or df.rdd.toDebugString